# Angular Boolean Pipe Yes/No localized

Tags: angular, localization, boolean, pipe

i need a handy way to get my yes-no pipe localized like the date pipe
`{{ my.date | date: 'short' : 'UTC' : 'de-DE' }}`

something like

```js
    {{ my.boolean | yesNo : "de-DE" }}
```

and instead of returning `value ? "Yes" : "No";` I need some magic :D

```js
    @Pipe({
      name: 'yesNo'
    })
    export class YesNoPipe implements PipeTransform {
    
      transform(value: boolean, ...args: unknown[]): string {
        // need some magic
        return value ? localizedYes : localizedNo;
      }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the 'select' feature in Angular's built in internationalization for translating Booleans:

Step 1 - set up internationalization in your app following the steps outlined in the Angular documentation. There's a good instructional video here: https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview

Step 2 - Prepare your component for translation.

Just say you have a component that looks like this:

```html
<span>{{myBooleanValue}}</span>
```

You can prepare it for translation by adding the i18n tag and the select feature:

```html
<span i18n>{ myBooleanValue, select, true {true} false {false}}</span>
```

Step 3 - extract your source text for translation by running *ng extract-i18n --output-path src/locale*

Step 4 - If you followed the video in Step 1, you should have an messages.xlf file with your source text, and a copy of it with your target language text. Copy the transunit from your source xlf to your target xlf and add the following target line below the source text in your trans unit:

```html
<source>{VAR_SELECT, select, true {true} false {false}}</source>
<target>{VAR_SELECT, select, true {verdadero} false {falso}}</target>
```

These show spanish translation for true/false. You could add yes/no instead in your target language.

Comment: This is awesome and exactly what i searched. Can use that for my new project as well

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, unlike `Date` which can be easily localize using JS, a simple "Yes" or "No" string have to be translated in order to achieve this. Here are some of the steps that I would go to achieve this:

1. Instal ngx-translate https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core and follow their guide for setup as well as create the translation resource files for all the languages that you want to be translated. If you don't like their documentation, here's a great article with an easy to follow guide https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-angular-app-with-ngx-translate
2. The rest is just using the translate service together with your pipe

```
    @Pipe({
      name: 'yesNo'
    })
    export class YesNoPipe implements PipeTransform {
    
      transform(value: boolean, ...args: unknown[]): string {
        return value ? 'KEY.YES' : 'KEY.NO';
      }
    
    }
    ...
    {{ my.boolean | yesNo | translate }}
```

It's a bit of a pain but this setup will scale infinitely for any future work that require localization/globalization.

Comment: Thanks @Nam
I was hoping to be able to go through this simple step before I set up the whole application multilingually

It's a pity, but I'll probably save more in the end if I do the "pain" right now :D

Thanks for your great answer!